# Should I split this table into two?

Tags: sql, normalization

I am trying to wrap my head around database normalization. This is my first time trying to create a working database so please forgive me for my ignorance.  I am trying to create an automated grad Check system for a class project.  The following table keeps track of all options for a major for a set number of catalog years.  The table is as follows

```
PID    Title    Dept    Courses    Must_have
```

Some options give the user a choice of a set number of classes out of the total listed (hence the `Must_have` attribute).   A completed row would look like this:

```
PID    Title    Dept    Courses    Must_have
--------------------------------------------
 1      bis     acct    201|202      NULL
```

`Title` is the name of the option that can come with the major.  If `bis` (business information systems) had a choice of classes, one row would have a number in the `Must_have` for only one row.

My question is should I split this table into two different tables?  I know the way I currently have it seems somewhat... well wrong.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: can you give an example to clarify "one row would have a number in the Must_have for only one row."

Comment: If an option required 4 courses out of 15 offered it would look like this:
1      bis     acct    201|202      4

Comment: Sorry, format the text well in the comments section :\

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would break dept into a separate table and associate it with a numeric ID. Then break your "courses" field into a "join table". Something like this:

**majors**

```
Id   Title       DepartmentID
```

**major_courses**

```
Id   MajorId     CourseId      MustHave
```

**departments**

```
Id   Title
```

So that, you may have a major like:

```
1    bis          1
```

a major_course like:

```
1    1           201            0
1    1           202            0
1    1           203            1 -- must have 203
```

then departments like:

```
1    bis
```

So now, to get a list of courses for the first major you can do this:

```
SELECT major_courses.CourseId, major_courses.MustHave, departments.Title 
FROM majors 
RIGHT JOIN major_courses ON major_courses.CourseId = majors.Id 
INNER JOIN departments ON departments.Id = majors.DepartmendID 
WHERE major.id = 1
```

Comment: I have more tables in my database that should handle Majors very similar to what you described.  I was hoping I would not have to make the options table as complicated, but it is looking like it is the best way to do it.  Thank you for your help :)

Answer (score 5):

I would split it into three tables. The first would be `majors` and would contain `PID, Title, Dept`, the second would be `courses`, containing the course ID, course name and any other information, and the last would be a mapping between majors and courses (perhaps named `courses_majors`). The `courses_majors` table would contain the ID of the major, the ID of a course and a flag to show whether or not it is required by that major.

(This is assuming that one course could be used in multiple majors)

Comment: Cool, thanks a lot.  I think I will split my tables like you described.

Comment: @nickf - Resolving the Many to Many seems to be a big Ahaaaa moment for a lot of us.

Comment: yeah, i still remember when someone showed me that technique for the first time!